# How to create a new sequential flag after a change in value (in SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I'm trying to create a sequential numeric flag upon a change in section.

The flag should be 1 when a student joins a section and continue to be 1 until a change in section.
The flag should be 2 for the first change, 3 for the 2nd change and so forth.

Since a section can repeat after a change, I'm finding it challenging to create a desired outcome.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Sample data**

```
create table dbo.cluster_test
(student_id int not null
,record_date date not null
,section varchar(30) null)

insert into cluster_test
(student_id, record_date, section)
values
 (123, '2020-02-06', NULL)
,(123, '2020-05-14', 'A')
,(123, '2020-08-12', 'A')
,(123, '2020-09-01', 'B')
,(123, '2020-09-15', 'A')
,(123, '2020-09-29', 'A')
,(123, '2020-11-02', NULL)
,(123, '2020-11-30', NULL)
,(789, '2020-01-12', NULL)
,(789, '2020-04-12', 'A')
,(789, '2020-05-03', NULL)
,(789, '2020-06-13', 'A')
,(789, '2020-06-30', 'B')
,(789, '2020-07-01', 'B')
,(789, '2020-07-22', 'A')
```

**Desired result**

| student_id | record_date | section | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2020-02-06 | NULL | NULL |
| 123 | 2020-05-14 | A | 1 |
| 123 | 2020-08-12 | A | 1 |
| 123 | 2020-09-01 | B | 2 |
| 123 | 2020-09-15 | A | 3 |
| 123 | 2020-09-29 | A | 3 |
| 123 | 2020-11-02 | NULL | NULL |
| 123 | 2020-11-30 | NULL | NULL |
| 789 | 2020-01-12 | NULL | NULL |
| 789 | 2020-04-12 | A | 1 |
| 789 | 2020-05-03 | NULL | NULL |
| 789 | 2020-06-13 | A | 2 |
| 789 | 2020-06-30 | B | 3 |
| 789 | 2020-07-01 | B | 3 |
| 789 | 2020-07-22 | A | 4 |

**Attempt:**

```
select
 student_id
,record_date
,section
,case when section is not null then row_number() over(partition by student_id, section order by record_date asc)
 end row#
,case when (section is not null) and (lag(section, 1) over(partition by student_id order by record_date asc) is null) then 'start'
      when (lag(section, 1) over(partition by student_id order by record_date asc) is not null) and (section != lag(section, 1) over(partition by student_id order by record_date asc)) then 'change'
 end chk_txt
,case when section is not null then (case when (section is not null) and (lag(section, 1) over(partition by student_id order by record_date asc) is null) then 1
                                          when (lag(section, 1) over(partition by student_id order by record_date asc) is not null) and (section != lag(section, 1) over(partition by student_id order by record_date asc)) then 1
                                          else 0
                                     end)
 end chk_val2
from cluster_test

order by 1, 2
```

Comment: If you had two `NULL` values in a row, what would the results be?

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff,
A new sequence number should be assigned for the following non-null row (for the student).
Best,
B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is gap and island problem. You can use analytical function as follows:

```
Select student_id, record_date, section,
    Case when section is not null 
        Then sum(case when section is not null and (section <> lgs or lgs is null) then 1 end) 
            over (partition by student_id order by record_date)
    End as flag
From (
    Select student_id, record_date, section,
        Lag(section) over (partition by student_id order by record_date) as lgs
    From cluster_test t
) t
order by student_id, record_date;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=02c46143a0c3b012c03dad03767ecf9a)

Comment: Thanks @DaleK. I have updated the answer and also added the db<>fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

You can go for multiple CTEs and get data as given below:

```sql
with cte_studentSection as (
    SELECT student_id, record_Date, section
        , lead(section) over(partition by student_id order by record_date) as nextSection
        , row_number() over (partition by student_id order by record_date) as rnk
    FROM dbo.Cluster_test
    where section is not null
), cte_studentSectionFlag as (
    SELECT Student_id, record_date, section, rnk, 1 as flag
    from cte_studentSection as oc
    where record_date = (SELECT MIN(record_Date) from cte_studentSection where student_id = oc.student_id)
    union all 
    SELECT oc.Student_id, oc.record_date, oc.section,oc.rnk, case when oc.section = cte.section then cte.flag else cte.flag + 1 end
    from cte_studentSection as oc
    inner join cte_studentSectionFlag as cte on cte.rnk + 1 = oc.rnk and oc.student_id = cte.student_id
)
select student_id, record_date, section, flag
from cte_studentsectionflag 
union all
select student_id, record_date, section, null as flag
from dbo.Cluster_test
where section is null
order by student_id, record_date;
```

| student_id | record_date | section | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2020-02-06 | NULL | NULL |
| 123 | 2020-05-14 | A | 1 |
| 123 | 2020-08-12 | A | 1 |
| 123 | 2020-09-01 | B | 2 |
| 123 | 2020-09-15 | A | 3 |
| 123 | 2020-09-29 | A | 3 |
| 123 | 2020-11-02 | NULL | NULL |
| 123 | 2020-11-30 | NULL | NULL |
| 789 | 2020-01-12 | NULL | NULL |
| 789 | 2020-04-12 | A | 1 |
| 789 | 2020-05-03 | NULL | NULL |
| 789 | 2020-06-13 | A | 1 |
| 789 | 2020-06-30 | B | 2 |
| 789 | 2020-07-01 | B | 2 |
| 789 | 2020-07-22 | A | 3 |

Comment: Hi @Venkataraman R. The flag for the new row after NULL should have a new sequence. It should be 2 in row 12.